# amsthm with \usepackage[french]{babel}

Tags: babel, amsthm, french

When I use `amsthm` with `\usepackage[french]{babel}`, I got `Proof` becoming `Démonstration`. In general, it is good, but in a special case of mine, I need it to be `Proof`. Could you help me to get this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     %% format d'encodage
\usepackage[french]{babel}      %% typographie française

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
This is a great theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
This is a simple proof.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the optional argument for `proof` to provide the required name:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     %% format d'encodage
\usepackage[french]{babel}      %% typographie française

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
This is a great theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}[Proof]
This is a simple proof.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need to change the name for *all* the `proof` environments you can use

```
\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand\proofname{Proof}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     %% format d'encodage
\usepackage[french]{babel}      %% typographie française

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand\proofname{Proof}}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
This is a great theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
This is a simple proof.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you. But could you show me how to make this default by \renewcommand?

Comment: @user565739 You're welcome. Sure. please see my updated answer.

Comment: @user565739 I updated with a better alternative.